# What would you call a person who clarifies matters?

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests, phrase-requests

A person who can put things, problems in a new light.
Makes you see things differently.
Helps you figure out things, solve problems.
Map complex issues etc.

Comment: This may depend on the context. What is the one who explains things: a parent, teacher, priest, scientist, writer...?

Comment: @jan I would say it about a consultant, or advisor. Definitely not a tutor, mentor or educator - thanks

Comment: @TheHan The problem with saying you want a word that applies to a consultant or an advisor but *not* to a tutor or mentor is that I can't think of any word that is so specific as that. For instance, if I say that somebody is an [**oracle**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oracle) ("a person giving wise or authoritative decisions or opinions"), anybody in any role could *also* be considered to be an oracle. Only *role*-type nouns will be specific, but they would likely be *too* specific. So, you're stuck with something too broad or something too narrow . . .

Comment: A *critical thinker*?

Answer (score 1):

**Consultant** = a person who gives professional or expert advice ([Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/consultant)). A company can hire a [professional consultant.](https://work.chron.com/professional-consultant-9684.html)

**Counsellor** = person trained to give guidance on personal or psychological problems ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/counsellor)). Examples are a marriage counsellor and a debt counsellor.

Answer (score 1):

The person you describe could be called an *elucidator*, meaning a person who has the ability to make something clear. An elucidator might, for example, put a problem into perspective, helping you to see it in a new light.

The [etymology](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/elucidator) of elucidator:

> Late Latin ēlūcidāre, ēlūcidāt- : Latin ē-, ex-, intensive pref.; see ex- + Latin lūcidus, **bright** (from lūcēre, **to shine** . . ..

*Elucidator* has cognates which include *lucid*, an adjective meaning clear; lucidity, a noun meaning the quality or attribute of being clear; and the verb *elucidate*, meaning to make clear. All four words carry with them the idea of light being brought to bear on something, making it clear and easily seen, hence understood. Here are sentences which include all four words:

> Jill is a great *elucidator*, and unraveling a complex problem and making it *lucid*, is her gift. *Lucidity* is exactly what we need when we get "stuck" while trying to unravel the complexity ourselves, and Jill performs a critically important role in helping to *elucidate* and solve our problem.

Comment: wow - that elucidated my mind... thanks.